# How to assign azure custom dns to public ip

Tags: azure, dns, kubernetes, azure-public-ip

I have resource group on azure containing virtual machine and kubernetes and load balancer and public ip address and etc.

I can access to my kubernetes app with direct public ip or public ip dns name. But problem is that i can't get azure custom dns (dns zone) working for my public ip. e.g. myapp.com

I have tried to assign public ip address in dns zone but not getting custom dns name working for my app.

Comment: have you done the delegation of your domain to azure dns with your domain registrar?

Answer (score 0):

2 options:
1. A record that points to public ip address explicitly
2. CNAME record that points to azure "internal" dns name

Comment: Actually i have tried A and CNAME but does not seems to work. Do i need to specify DNS zone name servers in some where?

in cmd command e.g. nslookup myapp.com says "can't find myapp.com: Non-existent domain"

cmd command nslookup myapp.com <name_server_name> i get name and ip.

Comment: sorry, i dont really understand, but you need to create a dns record in your dns zone or use azure provided one (you can map azure provided ip address to azure provided dns name which is configurable).

Comment: Basically i have done this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-portal

Answer (score 0):

From the description it looks like you haven't updated the name server settings of your domain (e.g. myapp.com) to use Azure DNS's name servers (where you have created a zone for that domain name) for query resolutions.

The article linked below has instructions on how to do it. Please let us know if this answers your question.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns